# PHP: foreach loop inside PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to dynamically generate html `select options` using PHP based on whatever its stored in mysql database.

the column that stores the data called `sizez`.

the data in that column is stored like so:

```
small,large,xlarge,xxlarge
```

so basically the data is separated by a comma.

now in my php page I simply pull the data and display it on my page using a `while loop` for each product that is stored in the mysql database.

the issue that I am having is that I need to generate a select option dropdown list based on the `sizez` column for each item.

for that I am using the `explode()` function and it will generate the select option successfully too.

however, the issue is that it will only get the strings from the first `sizez` column and ignores the rest of the items But it will display the string from the first column for other items too and it repeats them!

this is my code:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $id = $row["id"];
             $sizez = $row["sizez"];
             $sizez = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $sizez); //Remove dot at end if exists
             $array = explode(',', $sizez); //split string into array seperated by ','
             foreach($array as $value) //loop over values
             {
                 //echo $value . PHP_EOL; //print value
                 $sizesOption .='<option>'.$value.'</option>';
              }

$all_list .="<select>
         '.$sizesOption.'
         </select>";
```

so I thought to put the `foreach($array as $value)` inside the `$all_list .=` but that approach is wrong.

could someone please advise on this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The expected result should be like this:

```
item one              item two                 item three
small                 large                    small
large                 xxlarge                  xxlarge
```

However, with my code I get the result like this:

```
item one              item two                 item three
small                 small                    small
large                 large                    large
                      small                    small
                      large                    large
                                               small
                                               large
```

so basically, it will get the sizes column from the first item and it will repeat it inside select options for other items exactly like the example above.

Comment: So, if they are repeated, whats the expected result? Add some data regarding what you expect to get.

Comment: Don't store multiple values in one field like that  ("small,large,xlarge,xxlarge") - google about database normal forms......

Comment: There is something strange in the way you concat strings. try: `$all_list .="<select>".$sizesOption."</select>";`

Comment: If you have separate `<select>` for each iteration, than you have to reset `$sizesOptions` first. Better use `$sizesOptions = array(); ... $sizesOptions[] = "<option>{$value}</option>"; ... $all_list .= '<select>'.implode("\r\n", $sizesOptions)...`

Comment: @MilanG, adding a new table may or not may be the best idea, depends on the problem and on the dimension of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are generating separate `<select>` for each iteration, you have to reset `$sizeOptions`. I suggest using arrays instead of just concatenating strings:

```
$allList = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $sizesOption = array();
    $sizez = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $row["sizez"]);

    $array = explode(',', $sizez);

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $sizesOption[] = "<option>{$value}</option>";
    }

    $all_list[] = '<select>'.implode("\r\n", $sizesOption).'</select>';
}

echo implode("\r\n", $allList);
```

Comment: Thank you mate. a part of your answer helped me to solve the issue and I posted my own answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted it looks like you're regenerating $all_list in every iteration of your while loop.

So if you echo $all_list outside of the while loop it will only have the last iteration available - all the other ones having been overwritten during the process of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong. but as simple as:

```
$all_list ="<select>".$sizesOption."</select>";
```

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing now mate.

Comment: except one `.=` dot. don't you?

Comment: correct Alex. I think I figured it out. I will post an answer in a minute. I'm just a silly man..

Answer (score 0):

Close the opening braces for while loop before the  '$all_list .="' statement.You are iterating the statement inside while loop.

`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
             $id = $row["id"];
             $sizez = $row["sizez"];
             $sizez = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $sizez); //Remove dot at end if exists
             $array = explode(',', $sizez); //split string into array seperated by ','
             foreach($array as $value) //loop over values
             {
                 //echo $value . PHP_EOL; //print value
                 $sizesOption .='<option>'.$value.'</option>';
              }
}
$all_list .="<select>
         '.$sizesOption.'
         </select>";
```

`

May be this will work

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to Justinas's answer. I realized that I had to put my php variable inside the while loop.

so all I had to do was to put  `$sizesOption =array();` inside my while loop and everything works fine now.

P.S. i haven't made any other changes to my code above.

Comment: I my opinion this is wrong, because in your case (working with strings) you have to use `$sizesOption = '';` and not an empty array.

Comment: @skroczek, I agree with you but for some strange reason it works with either `array()` or `="";`. I'm going to change it to `="";` in case.

Comment: @TERO PHP is strange language, you can reassign variables even if it's type is different.